# Javascript bouncing ball - viewport to automatically resize animation canvas on load?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I'm looking to have a javascript bouncing ball in a responsive canvas.

My goal is for the animation canvas to be the same size of the viewport in which it loads instead of having a fixed sized canvas (currently 1366x768).

The problem is if someone loads the page on mobile with a 320px viewport they'll miss part of the animation and its sole purpose.

So far by trial and error I got to this script:

```
<script>
var context;
var x=100;
var y=200;
var dx=5;
var dy=5;

function init()
{
    context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(draw,10);
}

function draw()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0,1366,768);
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="#fedc00";
    // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
    context.arc(x,y,16,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    // Boundary Logic
    if( x<0 || x>1366) dx=-dx; 
    if( y<0 || y>768) dy=-dy; 
    x+=dx; 
    y+=dy;
}
</script>
```

and HTML

```
<body onLoad="init();">

<div class="canvas">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1366" height="768">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if this needs to be done in javascript or if the script should just not mention the canvas size at all (which should be 100% width/height of the viewport) and address it with media queries in the CSS?

Can you please give me some pointers as to what I need to add/remove from the script to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see in this part you're using fixed parameters:

```
// Boundary Logic
if( x<0 || x>1366) dx=-dx; 
if( y<0 || y>768) dy=-dy;
```

You're stretching the ball distance way beyond the size of the mobile screen. You should make these values dynamic.

```
window.innerWidth  //instead of 1366
window.innerHeigth //instead of 768
```

If you refresh the page with the browser window narrowed to for example 500px wide, the ball should now bounce when it reaches the right side of the window.

Anyway, this doesn't end here, we have to add an offset, which is the diameter of the ball, because you want it to look like it's bouncing.

Let me know if the above works and we will see the adjustments later.

Comment: Hi Juan, thank you for your reply. 

The ball now bounces on the right hand side of the window on smaller window sizes (320,480) but then it disappears. 

On 640 width or higher the ball just drops of the screen to never be seen again.

I'm still using values 1366, 768 in two other places as per code above - one time on the script and the other on the html.

How can I get the ball to bounce on any window size both top/bottom and sides of the browser window?

Comment: Managed to have the ball bouncing against the edges of all viewports by using original script and adding this to my CSS:
    
    #myCanvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 110%;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
    }

Problem now is since viewports do not have the same image ratio the ball get's distorted/squezeed/resized...

Thinking if there's a way to keep the ball's proportions unaffected by the viewport's ratio?

Comment: Can you update the question with all the CSS you have?

Comment: .wrapper {
 width: 100%; 
 position:relative; 
 padding-top: 5.5em;
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
    }

    .canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute; 
 text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: transparent;
    }

    #myCanvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 110%;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
    }